# composer install with prestissimo in docker container

Tags: docker, composer-php

I can try composer install in docker container on ubuntu16.04 image with hirak/prestissimo plugin.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
  && LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y php7.1 git vim supervisor curl unzip mysql-client wget \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends php7.1-cli php7.1-dev \
        php7.1-pgsql php7.1-sqlite3 php7.1-gd \
        php7.1-curl php7.1-memcached \
        php7.1-imap php7.1-mysql php7.1-mbstring \
        php7.1-xml php7.1-imagick php7.1-zip php7.1-bcmath php7.1-soap \
        php7.1-intl php7.1-readline php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-fpm

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN composer --no-interaction global require 'hirak/prestissimo'

COPY docker/config/ /config/

RUN cp /config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["/config/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  php71:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: mylogin/myimage
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - my-network
```

But when i run `composer-install` in my docker container parallel installation with hirak/prestissimo plugin doesn't work.

Comment: You'd almost never run "install" type commands inside a container; they tend to be expensive and anything they do is lost when the container exits.  Best practice is usually to `COPY` your application code in the Dockerfile and `RUN` the installation command, so it's done once at image built time and saved.

Comment: In case its a develop container you can run all composer comands in the container. Since the code is mounted as volume you would not loose contents of vendor.